# JHipster - Log Files

Tags: logging, jhipster

I have a JHipster application running and I would like to know where are the logs files. Where are they generated ? (It's a newbie question, but can't find anything)

I am on the "Dev" profile with the default configuration. (Didn't change anything regarding the application-dev.yml)

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok,

So here the answer to this:

There is a xml file **logback.xml** that you can find in the resources directory.

**Configuration for console:**

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <Pattern>[%p] %c - %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

**For a File**

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  ...
</appender>
```

**Reference it at the end of the file**

```
<root level="${logback.loglevel}">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/> <!-- For Console Log -->
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/> <!-- For File Log -->
</root>
```

Comment: I'm using jhipster v2.27.2, I don't have a logback.xml file, I do have a logback-spring.xml file but it doesn't matter what changes I do here they won't affect the output of my console logs. has anything changed? Thanks!

Comment: this is right it is now stored as logback-spring.xml uncomment the xml at top mentioning "FILE" and it will begin logging to a log file in root of the project

Comment: I enabled the comment but I didn't see any log file getting generated in root folder of the project. I added some info messages in main method but no log file got generated.

Answer (score 18):

The default jh configuration src\main\resourcess\logback-spring.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration scan="true">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

<!-- The FILE and ASYNC appenders are here as examples for a production configuration -->
<!--
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>utf-8</charset>
            <Pattern>%d %-5level [%thread] %logger{0}: %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <queueSize>512</queueSize>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </appender>
-->

    <logger name="com.theice.asdlc" level="#logback.loglevel#"/>

    <logger name="javax.activation" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="javax.mail" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="javax.xml.bind" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="ch.qos.logback" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="com.codahale.metrics" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="com.ryantenney" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="com.sun" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="com.zaxxer" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.apache" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory" level="OFF"/>
    <logger name="org.bson" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.validator" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" level="OFF"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.security" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.cache" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.thymeleaf" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.xnio" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="springfox" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="sun.rmi" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="liquibase" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="sun.rmi.transport" level="WARN"/>

    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>

    <root level="#logback.loglevel#">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

includes 
spring-boot-master\spring-boot\src\main\resources\org\springframework\boot\logging\logback\base.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
Base logback configuration provided for compatibility with Spring Boot 1.1
-->

<included>
 <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
 <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
 <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
 <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
 <root level="INFO">
  <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
  <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
 </root>
</included>
```

which includes defaults.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
Default logback configuration provided for import, equivalent to the programmatic
initialization performed by Boot
-->

<included>
 <conversionRule conversionWord="clr" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ColorConverter" />
 <conversionRule conversionWord="wex" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter" />
 <conversionRule conversionWord="wEx" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ExtendedWhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter" />

 <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}"/>
 <property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} ${PID:- } --- [%t] %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}"/>

 <appender name="DEBUG_LEVEL_REMAPPER" class="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LevelRemappingAppender">
  <destinationLogger>org.springframework.boot</destinationLogger>
 </appender>

 <logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory" level="ERROR"/>
 <logger name="org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase" level="ERROR"/>
 <logger name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" level="WARN"/>
 <logger name="org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils" level="WARN"/>
 <logger name="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool" level="WARN"/>
 <logger name="org.crsh.plugin" level="WARN"/>
 <logger name="org.crsh.ssh" level="WARN"/>
 <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle" level="ERROR"/>
 <logger name="org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version" level="WARN"/>
 <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.CrshAutoConfiguration" level="WARN"/>
 <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_LEVEL_REMAPPER"/>
 </logger>
 <logger name="org.thymeleaf" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_LEVEL_REMAPPER"/>
 </logger>
</included>
```

console-appender.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
Console appender logback configuration provided for import, equivalent to the programmatic
initialization performed by Boot
-->

<included>
 <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <encoder>
   <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
   <charset>utf8</charset>
  </encoder>
 </appender>
</included>
```

and finally file-appender.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
File appender logback configuration provided for import, equivalent to the programmatic
initialization performed by Boot
-->

<included>
 <appender name="FILE"
  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <encoder>
   <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
  </encoder>
  <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
   <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%i</fileNamePattern>
  </rollingPolicy>
  <triggeringPolicy
   class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
   <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
  </triggeringPolicy>
 </appender>
</included>
```

which is creating a spring.log file in the temp directory that rolls every 10MB.

Here is a version that may be more appropriate for production.

It enables the async file appender, and replaces the temp directory spring.log with debug, info (without trace or debug), and error (without info,trace,debug) log files in the catalina_base directory that roll each day.

It uses an easily-parsed splunk format, and column widths that are easy for humans to scan.

It includes columns that a simple Servlet Filter can use to add values to MDC for: IP=IP Address, S=Session Id, TX=Transaction Id, U=User Id.  eg org.slf4j.MDC.put("TX", java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()); :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration scan="true">
 <conversionRule conversionWord="clr" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ColorConverter" />
 <conversionRule conversionWord="wex" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter" />
 <conversionRule conversionWord="wEx" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ExtendedWhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter" />

  
  <!-- Write logs to Tomcat instance logs directory or current directory -->
 <property name="LOG_ROOT"            value="${CATALINA_BASE:-.}"/>
 <property name="LOG_PATH"            value="${LOG_ROOT}/logs"/>
 <property name="LOG_ARCHIVE_PREFIX"  value="${LOG_PATH}/APPID-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-"/>
 <property name="LOG_ARCHIVE_DAYS"    value="5"/>
  
  <!-- Patterns assume Servlet Filter adds values to MDC for: IP=IP Address, S=Session Id, TX=Transaction Id, U=User Id.  eg org.slf4j.MDC.put("TX", java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString());  -->
 <property name="LOG_PATTERN"         value="%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} ,ip=%-16.16X{IP} ,s=%-32.32X{S} ,x=%-30.30X{TX} ,l=%-5.5level ,u=%-12.12X{U} ,c=%-30.30logger{0} ,f=%-20.20method ,t=%-15.15t ,m=%-80m ,cf=%logger %n"/>  
  <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} ,ip=%-3.3X{IP} ,s=%-8.8X{S} ,x=%-8.8X{TX} ,l=%-5.5level ,u=%-8.8X{U} ,c=%-30.30logger{0} ,f=%-20.20method ,t=%-10.10t ,m=%m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}"/>
  
 <!--
 <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(- - -){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}"/>
  <property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} ${PID:- } - - - [%t] %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}"/> 
  -->
  
 <appender name="DEBUG_LEVEL_REMAPPER" class="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LevelRemappingAppender">
  <destinationLogger>org.springframework.boot</destinationLogger>
 </appender>

 <logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory" level="ERROR"/>
 <logger name="org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase" level="ERROR"/>
 <logger name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" level="WARN"/>
 <logger name="org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils" level="WARN"/>
 <logger name="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool" level="WARN"/>
 <logger name="org.crsh.plugin" level="WARN"/>
 <logger name="org.crsh.ssh" level="WARN"/>
 <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle" level="ERROR"/>
 <logger name="org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version" level="WARN"/>
 <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.CrshAutoConfiguration" level="WARN"/>
 <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_LEVEL_REMAPPER"/>
 </logger>
 <logger name="org.thymeleaf" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_LEVEL_REMAPPER"/>
 </logger>


<!-- <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/> -->

 <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <encoder>
   <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
   <charset>utf8</charset>
  </encoder>
 </appender>
<!--
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <encoder>
   <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
  </encoder>
  <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
   <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%i</fileNamePattern>
  </rollingPolicy>
  <triggeringPolicy
   class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
   <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
  </triggeringPolicy>
 </appender>
-->

    <appender name="DEBUG_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender"><File>${LOG_PATH}/debug.log</File>    
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>DEBUG</level>
          <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>INFO</level>
          <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>TRACE</level>
          <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>WARN</level>
          <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>ERROR</level>
          <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        </filter>    
        <encoder><charset>utf-8</charset><pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern></encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy"><FileNamePattern>${LOG_ARCHIVE_PREFIX}debug.log</FileNamePattern><maxHistory>${LOG_ARCHIVE_DAYS}</maxHistory></rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="INFO_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender"><File>${LOG_PATH}/info.log</File>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>DEBUG</level>
          <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>INFO</level>
          <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>TRACE</level>
          <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>WARN</level>
          <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>ERROR</level>
          <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder><charset>utf-8</charset><pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern></encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy"><FileNamePattern>${LOG_ARCHIVE_PREFIX}info.log</FileNamePattern><maxHistory>${LOG_ARCHIVE_DAYS}</maxHistory></rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ERROR_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender"><File>${LOG_PATH}/error.log</File>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>DEBUG</level>
          <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>INFO</level>
          <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>TRACE</level>
          <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>WARN</level>
          <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>ERROR</level>
          <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder><charset>utf-8</charset><pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}</pattern></encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy"><FileNamePattern>${LOG_ARCHIVE_PREFIX}error.log</FileNamePattern><maxHistory>${LOG_ARCHIVE_DAYS}</maxHistory></rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <queueSize>512</queueSize>
        <appender-ref ref="INFO_FILE" />
      <appender-ref ref="ERROR_FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_FILE"/>
    </appender>

 <root level="INFO">
  <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
  <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_FILE" />
  <appender-ref ref="INFO_FILE" />
  <appender-ref ref="ERROR_FILE" />
 </root>


    
    <logger name="com.theice.asdlc" level="#logback.loglevel#"/>

    <logger name="javax.activation" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="javax.mail" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="javax.xml.bind" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="ch.qos.logback" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="com.codahale.metrics" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="com.ryantenney" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="com.sun" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="com.zaxxer" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.apache" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory" level="OFF"/>
    <logger name="org.bson" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.validator" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" level="OFF"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.security" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.cache" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.thymeleaf" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.xnio" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="springfox" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="sun.rmi" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="liquibase" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="sun.rmi.transport" level="WARN"/>

    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>

    <root level="#logback.loglevel#">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for sharing

Comment: I would recommend doing a diff on your old logback-spring.xml file and this new file before just copy pasting this. Your old config will likely have loggers that you need to add to this answer that this answer couldn't have known about. For instance if you enabled ecache when creating your JHipster app, you will probably want the ecache logger. In your old logback-spring.xml file, you probably want to change the "includes" to just inline the included bits before you run the diff to see if anything is missing there too, but I haven't verified if it matters.

Comment: On newer versions of Spring, you'll need to get rid of the DEBUG_LEVEL_REMAPPER appender as the spring class it uses doesn't exist anymore (and seems to be unnecessary now? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50407297/3470632). You'll want to change the loggers that rely on it to not use it as well. I think you wouldn't need the additive=false properties anymore either, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

The **src/main/resources/logback.xml** file contains the JHipster logging configuration. *For reference, there is an additional **src/test/resources/logback-test.xml** file that is used when running the unit tests.*

By default, JHipster logs only to the console. When running using the `mvn spring-boot:run` or `gradlew bootRun` (the default build targets), the only place your logs will appear is in the console window. However, if running inside a web container such as Tomcat, the web container might automatically save the logs to a container-specific location. For example, Tomcat saves all log messages printed to the console to **[CATALINA_HOME]/logs/catalina.out**.

If you wish to reconfigure your application to print logs to a file, you can do so by uncommenting and customizing the **FILE** appender declaration in the logback configuration file mentioned above and then adding a reference to the **FILE** appender to the root logger. Example:

```
...

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <Pattern>%d %-5level [%thread] %logger{0}: %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

...

<root level="${logback.loglevel}">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/> <!-- Optionally remove this -->
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/> <!-- Add this -->
</root>

...
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't dug into this but will soon. I think it works similar to log4j/slf4j.  You need to define an appender with a file specification.  http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Rob

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, but after making lot of changes log files are getting changed , but log messages are not inserted in the log file.

I made the following changes to logback-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<!--<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <Pattern>[%p] %c - %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>-->
```

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <Pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <queueSize>512</queueSize>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</appender>

<logger name="com.myolo" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="com.myolo" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="com.myolo" level="ERROR"/>
<logger name="javax.activation" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="javax.mail" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="javax.xml.bind" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="ch.qos.logback" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="com.codahale.metrics" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="com.ryantenney" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="com.sun.xml.internal.bind" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="com.zaxxer" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="io.undertow" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="net.sf.ehcache" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.apache" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory" level="OFF"/>
<logger name="org.bson" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.validator" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" level="OFF"/>
<logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.web" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.security" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.cache" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.thymeleaf" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="org.xnio" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="springfox" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="sun.rmi" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="liquibase" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="sun.rmi.transport" level="WARN"/>

<contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
    <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
</contextListener>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</root>

<logger name="com.myolo">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Dev mode, modifying logback-spring.xml only creates log file but does not log data to this file (file is created but empty).
I had to add "file" key into "logging" key in applicatio-dev.yml file:

logging:

```
file: *path/log_file_name.log*
```

(for example:

logging:

```
file: logs/application1.log
```

)