# Replacement for Logback LevelRemappingAppender in Spring Boot 2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I'm migrating an application from Spring Boot 1.x to 2.x and I found some entries in the logback configuration which use a `LevelRemappingAppender`, like this:

```
<appender name="DEBUG_LEVEL_REMAPPER" class="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LevelRemappingAppender">
    <destinationLogger>org.springframework.boot</destinationLogger>
</appender>
```

`org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LevelRemappingAppender` doesn't exist in Boot 2 and I can't find a replacement nor any mention in the migration guide.

Is there an easy way to include this Logback remapping functionality in Spring Boot 2?

Comment: Looks like it's no longer required in Spring Boot 2 because the logging events it was remapping no longer exist at INFO level. More details [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7657).