# Change logback log level

Tags: java, logging, logback

Given third party library whose source code I cannot change:

```
package thirdpartylibrary;
class ThirdPartyClass {
    void thirdPartyMethod() {
        log.error("Something happened");
    }
}
```

In the log file I would like to see:

```
INFO Something happened
```

instead of:

```
ERROR Something happened
```

**How to change log level for `thirdpartylibrary.ThirdPartyClass` via `logback.xml` or similar configuration?**

I am aware that I could turn off logging via:

```
<logger name="thirdpartylibrary.ThirdPartyClass" level="OFF"/>
```

But then I would not know that `Something happened` at all.

Reason why I would like to achieve it is that I would like to take log levels seriously as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8021604/2866645

I.e. ERROR level should mean that our operations team should be woken up at 2AM.

I would like to eliminate false positives.

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Indeed org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LevelRemappingAppender looks exactly as what I was looking for. Unfortunatelly, it is no longer available in Spring Boot 2.0, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407297/replacement-for-logback-levelremappingappender-in-spring-boot-2. So I wonder if there is elegant way that would work with Logback 1.2 & Spring Boot 2.0. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you could just add the original code in your own project? See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/e92e56dda5d4ed35479b0797bbdd486551665663#diff-8c36970abc3c64173beb3a6f9f4a9375

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you override the log.error method of your logging library and get the class/package name of the class trying to log the message via the level ERROR. if the package/class is one of your third party you can change the level of the log message.

it should be something like this

```
if(object.className == thirdParty)
{
 log.info(message);
}
```