# Could not create an Appender of type [org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LevelRemappingAppender]

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

Recently did a jump in version for the `org.springframework.boot` plugin from 1.5.x to 2.3.x in my build.gradle file. I have been going up by increments as suggested by my coworkers and encountered this issue at spring 2.0.x stating:

`Could not create an Appender of type [org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LevelRemappingAppender]. ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LevelRemappingAppender`

and no matter what version I am using past 2.x.x the issue doesnt seem to resolve. I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407297/replacement-for-logback-levelremappingappender-in-spring-boot-2) on here talking about a replacement for the `LevelRemappingAppender` and then someone answered saying it was not needed anymore.

Im not sure exactly what I need in order to resolve this error as it is only an issue for me past spring 2.x.x. Has anyone come across this before, if so do you have a solution or even a doc I could use to solve it